# How to find all the pairs of tuples that agree on a certain attribute

Tags: sql, select, db2

I am trying to write a query in db2 for a database that has books and the customers who bought them and I am to find the pairs of customers who bought common books.

Say for example the DB is called "DB" and it looks like this

```
CustomerID   Book            Cost
1            Harry Potter    12
2            SOUE             6
3            Harry Potter    12
4            Harry Potter    12
5            SOUE             6
6            SOUE             6
```

I am basically trying to get the resulting table look like

```
Customer1    Customer2
1            3
1            4
2            5
2            6
```

I have tried using group by's but I cant seem to get the idea right

I've tried

```
Select book
from DB
group by book
```

which uniquely gives me all the books but I don't know how I would go about getting the customer pairs. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd self-join according to the `book` column. In order to avoid conceptual duplicates (e.g., 1-3 and 3-1), you could make an arbitrary decision to always display the lower customer ID on the left:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.customerid, b.customerid
FROM   mytable a
JOIN   mytable b ON a.book = b.book AND a.customerid < b.customerid
```

**EDIT:**

To answer the question in the comments, if you want to display customer names instead of ids, you'd need to join the customers table to this query, **twice**, once for each column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.name AS customer1, cb.name AS customer2
FROM   purchases pa
JOIN   purchases pb ON pa.book = pb.book AND pa.customerid < pb.customerid
JOIN   customers ca ON pa.customer_id = ca.id
JOIN   customers cb ON pb.customer_id = cb.id
```

Comment: awesome this seems to work great, just another follow up question, if i had another table with the customers names and their customer id's how would i go about displaying in my final query only the names of the pairs instead of the customerid's? thank you so much :)

Comment: @SaadQamer sure - you just need another couple of joins. See my edited answer for the details.

Comment: okay got it thank you so much its going to take me a bit to understand everything but I'm starting to understand the logic of it thank you so much ! :)

Comment: sorry just one last follow up, if i wanted to change the title of the resultant table like so now i have a 2 column table being outputted and they both have the field name as "NAME" if i wanted to change it to customer1 and customer2, how would i go about doing that?